# Install Ubuntu in Dell Inspiron 3670

Tags: system-installation

I tried to install Ubuntu 18.04 in a Dell Inspiron 3670. It looks it's starting to install Ubuntu, but I get this message instead:

```
No Signal
Entering the power saving mode shortly.
```

[image: install 1]

[image: install 2]

[image: install 3]

Comment: Do you have another video card installed in that system? Sometimes installers will switch to the built in video card. If you have another video card installed, you might need to disable the built in vga in bios or plug a monitor into the built in vga to see if the installer is switching to that (at least long enough for enough drivers to load to start using your additional video card).

Comment: If you have an add-on Nvidia graphics card you need and additional boot parameter. With Try or Install selected press "e" to edit and add `nomodeset` to the line with "quiet splash", confirm and boot the installer. You'll probably need to do the same in the installed system until you install the recommended Nvidia graphics drivers.

Comment: Hello, Marc Ritterbusch, GabrielaGarcia,

Thank you so much for your greatest help!

That works!

Thanks again!

With Best,

Yue